# AMD and Nvidia Same Computer XMR-Stak

Tags: gpu-mining

I'm mining with a 1070, and I have a 580 lying around. Is it possible to mine on XMR-Stak with both AMD and Nvidia GPUs in the same system? To do this, I would need to purchase a new motherboard, and possible case, as I'm running an mATX build right now.

Would it be worth it to go for the bigger board and extra slots? Or am I better off selling the 580 and the 1070, and go for a better card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to mine on **XMR-Stak** with CPU, AMD GPUs and Nvidia GPUs in the same system at the same time. Take a look at [Monero Mining Wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index) on Reddit for more info on building a **Monero** mining rig and how to configure software.

In your case, the problem isn't mATX board, but how many PCI-E slots on it. Supposing that you're using the only full-size PCI-E x16 slot, maybe you have some PCI-E x1 slots free and you can use them with risers to add other cards to your rig.

If you plan to go big in mining, also a motherboard with many PCI-E slots could be helpful and you will need some risers. Get the ones that fit in a PCI-E x1 slot, since they also fit in the larger PCI-E x16 slots. Lastly, Nvidia 1070 and AMD RX 580 are nice cards for Monero mining and a good starting point for sure, I will remain with them.